# How can I select an input field when an anchor is clicked using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a reply feature on my website where if the reply button is clicked it slides the reply section.
How could I select the input element when that reply button is clicked?

```
<a href="#" onclick="slide('reply');$('#replyinput').select();">Reply</a>
<div id="reply">
<input id="replyinput" />
</div>
```

Comment: please share the respective html

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. How do you expect us to answer without seeing even one character of code or markup?

Comment: i have added a basic version of the markup

Comment: `onlick` is a very different event handler, usually used for inputs, not links.

Comment: @Archer licking an input???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be

```
<a href="#" onclick="slide('reply');$('#replyinput').focus();return false">Reply</a>
```

Comment: I don't think you have to stop propagation or prevent default behaviour here, the `return false;` statement could/should be omitted, that depends of what OP is expecting. Anyway, you fix onclick error +1

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo error. It should be `onclick` and not `onlick`

```
<a href="#" onclick="slide('reply');$('#replyinput').select();">Reply</a>
```

Use `.select` if you want the field and value selected. Use `.focus` to set the cursor to the field.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/pVqqL/)